# Windows 7 OEM disk missing i386 directory - DriverPacks BASE

Tags: windows-7, oem, slipstream

I'm trying to use [DriverPacks BASE 10.06](http://driverpacks.net/applications/driverpacks-base/10.06) to slipstream my Windows 7 Ultimate OEM cd, but when I use the standard "disk" option, it says I need to locate a valid source, the i386 folder.  Apparently, my disk doesn't have one.  My XP does, and I was able to slipstream it easily.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need a different slipstream program?  I've tried RT Seven lite, but have had major trouble integrating the DriverPacks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 7 install disk doesn't have an i386 folder anymore. Check out these tutorials on the DriverPacks forums on how to add the DriverPacks to your install disk:
http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=6098 
http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=4954